# Remove folder & all files in directory without glob()

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to delete all files in a Cloud Storage directory using the [functions that are available to me](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/advanced) in Google App Engine.

Normally, I could do something like this but `glob()` is not allowed:

```
$files = glob('gs://bucket/folder/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuart states that it is supported now, but to answer the question for future reference:

```
if($handle = opendir("gs://bucket/folder/")) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if(!is_dir("gs://bucket/folder/$file")) {
            unlink("gs://bucket/folder/$file");
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Good thinking. I know my question didn't say this, but do you mind adding in how to delete the folder as well?

Comment: what's wrong with the code snipper in the question?

Comment: Nothing if `glob` is available.  I was answering _Remove folder & all files in directory without glob()_

Comment: Nice and clean answer! (And an undeserved down vote)

Answer (score 4):

Glob is allowed since 1.9.18, and works just fine with Cloud Storage Buckets.

The docs need updating.